# Print my name letter by letter using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

How do I print each letter of my name using for loop in Java?

I tried to read tutorials on the Internet but it seems like none of those shows what I'm looking for. What I want to achieve is that once I typed my name it will print the letters one by one alternately.

Comment: Check out String.charAt(i) and String.length()

Comment: or "myString".toCharArray() and an enhanced for loop. two lines of code should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you have String type "YourName"
which you can access letter-by-letter using `charAt()` method

so the code would look like:

```
String name = "YourName";
for (int i=0; i < name.length; i++) {
    Systerm.out.println(name.charAt(i));
}
```

This will print every letter in separate line.